# How can I make my error messages more specific for users registering?

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I am currently working on the backend of my MEAN stack app. When users register, I want to check is specific fields are filled in or not. I currently have it setup where it will send a json object when submitted.

```
{ success: true, msg: "User registered successfully }
```

---

Here is how I currently have my register post route setup:

```js
exports.register = (req, res) => {
  let newUser = new User({
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
    username: req.body.username.toLowerCase(),
    password: req.body.password,
    dob: req.body.dob,
    gender: req.body.gender
  });

  User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({ success: false, msg: 'Failed to register user' });
    } else {
      res.json({ success: true, msg: 'User registered' });
    }
  });
};
```

I want to setup more specific error handling. For example, if first name isn't filled out, or if user isn't old enough based on their dob, etc.

If you need any more info let me know and I will update my original post.

Answer (score 0):

This question is *really* broad; there are many ways you could do such a thing, including simply writing code to check each field, produce a unique error message for each field name, and return a list of errors in JSON; you can then display these error messages to the user.

If you're looking for popular ways to do this with express, then [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/index.html) might be what you're looking for. Follow the Getting Started guide and see if it would suit your needs.